# Form not submitting to correct url in django

Tags: html, django, forms

Im making a web app in django and im having a problem with a form which isnt submitting to the correct place
searcc.html

```
<form method='POST', action='/saveApply'">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="JobSub">  
          <input value="{{user.id}}" name="usrid">
          <input value="{{comp.id}}" name="compid">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

views.py

```
def saveApply(request):
    current_user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST': # Foreign key to User is just the username
        savedApply.objects.create(
            user = request.POST.get('usrid'),
            company = request.POST.get('company')
        )
        return render('main/profile.html') # Change later

    return redirect('login')
```

The confusing thing is, when I press on the submit button Im not even getting sent to the login view. I am getting sent to the home page. I think the problem has something to do with the fact that this html page is getting included in another.
main.html

```
{% include 'main/search.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Main.html is also inheriting from another file
Urls.py

```
path('saveApply/', views.saveApply, name="saveApply"),
path('feed/', views.feed, name='feed'),
```

Comment: can you add your |urls.py| file of the app that holds the saveApply view?

Comment: Provide correct form endpoint in the action attribut of your form: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Attribute/action

Comment: I have added urls.py